# Continuity of Wiener measure on open balls

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $\mu$ be the Wiener measure on $C_0 [0, T]$, the space of continuous functions starting at $0$, under the sup norm.

**Question:** Is it true that the function $r \mapsto \mu(B_r(x))$ is continuous in $r$ for all $x \in C_0 [0, T]$? Might it even be differentiable?

*Note: Here $B_r (x)$ denotes the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$.*

Comment: Equivalently, this is studying the function $$f(r):=P(\underset{0\leq t\leq T}{\sup}\left|B_{t}-x(t)\right|<r)$$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064700/sample-path-of-brownian-motion-within-epsilon-distance-of-continuous-function. This goes under the name of small ball estimates: see work by Wenbo Li for various upper bounds that might be helpful http://www.jamesyli.com/wenbo_li/papers/01-survey-LiShao.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the references! I am aware of bounds on balls but not in this level of detail.